Is it possible to use a checkbox to filter results in Google Sheets?
I have a sheet that looks like this:

I would like a formula that filters based on the checkbox in D1. Ideally: if D1=FALSE, do nothing, otherwise filter. Is it possible to do this? I have written the following formula as a custom filter:
=IF(D1=FALSE, "", IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "B"), true, false))

But it doesn't seem to care about the checkbox.
To clarify - this would be added by clicking the filter button next to Filter 1 -> Filter by condition -> Custom formula is
Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Aa3UNY4Fl9nGoHjsbcSYaeDoS7c8EdmLv3dNQ3LY_g


You may try:
=if($D$1,find("B",A2),true)


IMPORTANT
Each & everytime after you enable/disable checkbox in D1 → you also need to click on filter symbol again & click on OK button for the output to refresh
